# In python script i have insert query but when i want insert multiple columns in the same query it gives error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, amazon-s3

In python script i have insert query but when i want insert multiple columns in the same query it gives error.
but for single query it works perfectly.
Below is my code.
my database AWS S3.

```
A = [] #
for score_row in score:
    A.append(score_row[2])
    print("A=",A)

B = [] #
for day_row in score:
    B.append(day_row[1])
    print("B=",B)
for x,y in zip(A,B):
    sql = """INSERT INTO calculated_corr_coeff(date,Day) VALUES (?,?)"""
    cursor.executemany(sql, (x,),(y,))
```

when i replace above query with following sql insert statement it works perfect.

```
sql = """INSERT INTO calculated_corr_coeff(date,Day) VALUES (?)"""
cursor.executemany(sql, (x,))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your code like this:

```
sql = """INSERT INTO calculated_corr_coeff(date,Day) VALUES (?,?)"""
cursor.execute(sql, (x,y,))  #<-- here
```

Because is just a onet insert ( not several inserts )

**Explanation**

I guess you are mistaked about number of inserts ( rows ) and number of paràmeters ( fields to insert on each row ). When you want to insert several rows, use `executemany`, just for one row you should to use `execute`. Second parapeter of `execute` is the "list" (or sequence ) of values to be inserted in this row.

**Alternative**

You can try to change syntax and insert all data in one shot using [** syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters):

```
values = zip(A,B)   #instead of "for"
sql = """INSERT INTO calculated_corr_coeff(date,Day) VALUES (?,?)"""
cursor.executemany(sql, **values )
```

Notice this approach don't use `for` statement. This mean all data is send to database in one call, this is more efficient.